# offscreen jquery element is causing horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I have an element offscreen that comes into the screen on click. Problem is instead of it actually being off screen, it's expanding my document horizontally so I'm getting a scroll bar at the bottom of the page.

Here's the site: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev4/

Here's the html:

```
<div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="dashboard">
                <nav id="access">
                    <div class="open"></div><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
                </nav>
            </div> <!-- dashboard -->
        </div> <!-- span12 -->
    </div> <!-- row-fluid -->
```

Here's the css:

```
#container-fluid {
  width:1280px;
}

.row-fluid .span12 {
  width: 100%;
  *width: 99.94680851063829%;
}

#dashboard {
  font-size:30px;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  right: -659px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#access {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width:730px;
}

.open {
  background: #cabd32 url(images/open.png) top left no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  float:left;
  padding: 32px 35px 33px;
}

.close {
  background: #cabd32 url(images/close.png) top left no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  float:left;
  padding: 32px 35px 33px;
}
```

And here's the script: (written by @AlexCheuk)

```
$('.open').bind('click',function(){ 
    $('#dashboard').stop().animate(
    {
        right: $(this).hasClass('close') ? '-659px' : '0'
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest seems to be:

add `body {overflow:hidden;}` or maybe use `overflow-x`

Comment: Ah, brilliant, did not realize I had the ability to define overflow by x and y. Thanks @tim!

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your CSS

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Will I not lose the ability to scroll vertically as well then?

Comment: @Damien okay.. why is that. Seems like the my answer is the same as the answer.

Comment: @AlexCheuk - Because setting a overflow: hidden on your body ruins this particular website for any device with a screen (or browser size) smaller than 1280x1000 pixels. Since scrolling is impossible the content will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

in body css, add

```
overflow:hidden
```